# Magento Main menu custom links

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

In magento the main menu is working based on category list. Here I want the categories as well as I want to add two more links which are not category.

The links should leads to 
1. CMS page link
2. Contact us link

If I add any category its become category page how can I insert my own links into category main navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

Although not free [Advanced Menu](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/1032/advanced-menu) can do this for you.